# Wi-Fi connection stops working

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, network-manager

I have a notebook with `QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter`. Initially it doesn't work on ubuntu 16.04.

I've copied this firmware files:

`https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/tree/master/QCA6174`

into `/lib/firmware/ath10k`.

I've also renamed file `/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-4.bin_WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1` to `firmware-4.bin`
and `/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-5.bin_SW_RM.1.1.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1` to `firmware-5.bin`.

Now network-manager see wifi adapter and connects. It works fine but after a while internet stops working.

There are no error messages in `journalctl -ru NetworkManager.service` in this moment.

And wi-fi works again after `sudo service network-manager restart`

This is my `iwconfig`:

```
wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"MyWiFi"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: D4:6E:0E:51:3F:AE   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=52/70  Signal level=-58 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:41   Missed beacon:0

enp7s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

And `lshw -class network`

```
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 32
       serial: 58:00:e3:f6:bd:6f
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.13.0-36-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00051-QCARMSWP-1 ip=192.168.0.104 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:320 memory:94000000-941fffff
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

> It works fine but after a while internet stops working.

Please try disabling power saving in Network Manager. From the terminal:

```
sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Any improvement?

**EDIT**: Be certain that you have the latest possible firmware. Please open a terminal and do:

```
cd /tmp
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.169.3_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement.

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: Problem is not fixed...

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few minutes.

Comment: thank you. I did it but wi-fi stops working in unpredictable way and I need some time to check it

Comment: it didn't help...