# Ubuntu 17.10 on Surface Pro 3, WiFi turns itself off after a while. Any ideas?

Tags: wireless, 17.10, surface

I am training in the use of Ubuntu since I am becoming a developer. I haven't used Ubuntu in years tho.
So I format Windows 10 out of my Surface Pro 3 and I install Ubuntu 17.10.
Everything works fine so far except the WiFi starts dying off after a certain period of time until it becomes disabled by itself!
When it becomes disabled the only thing that seems to fix it is restarting the computer.
But I can't be restarting my Surface every 30minutes!
Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013222/wi-fi-connection-stops-working/1013239#1013239

Comment: Well, mine is version 17.10 it might have different implications!
If the solution is the same I will remove it!
Also, it is on a Microsoft Surface Pro 3. This might make a difference also!
Thanks though!

Comment: Also, the solution offered at the possible duplicate thread doesn't seem to work at all! My WiFI becomes disabled and I am unable to re-enable it!

Comment: Disabling power saving in Network Manager is the same in any computer; the duped notebook, your Surface Pro or my Lenovo T440p.  It is unlikely, if the commands were entered correctly, that it disabled your wireless. Something else is wrong. Please provide the wireless diagnostics as described here and we'll find and fix it. https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180

Comment: Looks like my connection has stabilized. I was able to update the drivers through the Terminal. The user interface thinks there's no connection but it says I am up to date and everything else works.
Should I leave it like that?

Comment: I wouldn't leave it like that. Let's try to fix it. Please run: `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and also: `cat /etc/network/interfaces` Paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Here goes Network Manger Conf.:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/RBSjdS9bJW/

Comment: This thread is also working on my issue:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/715345/network-manager-is-not-detecting-wifi-networks
It seems that the folder /etc/network/interfaces is causing so trouble, or not.

Comment: Your paste says the wireless is working now. "The user interface thinks there's no connection " Which one? Network Manager? Update Manager Or...which?

Comment: update manager. But i can update from command line. So it's ok.